# Что за проблема?from app.handlers import router ImportError: cannot import name 'router' from 'app.handlers' aiogram3

Tags: telebot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher

 from app.handlers import router
 from config import TOKEN



 async def main():
 bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
 dp = Dispatcher()
 dp.include_router(router)
 await dp.start_polling(bot)



if __name__ == '__main__': 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, stream=sys.stdout)
try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exit')


   это уже файл handlers.py который находится в папке app
   from aiogram import Router
   from aiogram.types import Message
   from aiogram.filters import CommandStart


 router = Router()


 @router.message(CommandStart())
 async def cmd_start(message: Message):
 await message.answer('Добро пожаловать!')


from app.handlers import router
ImportError: cannot import name 'router' from 'app.handlers'
```

Comment: вот сама ошибка from app.handlers import router
ImportError: cannot import name 'router' from 'app.handlers'

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не обозначили папку как модуль Python, добавьте пустой файл `__init__.py` в папку `handlers` и `app`

Comment: handlers это не папка а файл .py, папка только app

Answer (score 0):

У вас очень сильно поехало форматирование вопроса.
Если файлы расположены так:

```
app
-- main.py
-- handlers
   -- router.py
```

то надо в папку handlers добавить пустой файл `__init__.py` и импортировать как

```
from handlers import router
```

Чтобы было так:

```
app
-- main.py
-- handlers
   -- __init__.py
   -- router.py
```

Comment: handlers это не папка а файл .py, папка только app

Comment: Тогда достаточно просто `import handlers`, а в коде `handlers.router`